# Many insert/updates in a row stop MySQL from working on my Joomla site using Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, joomla, connection

I am currently working on a Joomla website on a Unix server. There are no users connected at the moment because I'm the only one who can access it (so no heavy traffic). During testing, I proceed to several inserts or updates on a table of my MySql DB. The insert/update is triggered using an Ajax call to a php file which handles the connection using jFactory::getDBO(), performs the insert or the update and returns a success response to Ajax. Everything works perfectly. But if I run several tests in rapid succession, after a while, even though I still get a success response in Ajax, no insert or update is performed (not on this table, not on any other table). It's like MySql blocks all the connections (and yet I don't get any error message). I tried opening a different browser and magically the insert/update works perfectly from there. I think I noticed that it starts working again also when I close the original browser and open it again. What could the issue be ? And how can I solve it ? I was looking for a way to close the getDBO() connections after each query, but all I found online is that on a Unix server, this type of connection is automatically closed after each query. Thanks so much for your support !

EDIT:

This is how the insert/updates are performed:

```
if(isset($step) && !empty($step) && trim($step) != ""){

    $sql = "UPDATE #__thamatho_student_mistakes SET   
    date_mistake='".$date."', answer='".addslashes($answer)."' WHERE 
    student=".$userid." and step=".$steid;
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $db->query();

}else{  

    $sql = "Insert into #__thamatho_student_mistakes (`student`, 
    `step`, `answer`, `date_mistake`) values (".$userid.", ".$steid.", 
    '".addslashes($answer)."', '".$date."')";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $db->query();

}
```

Comment: Try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is really not related to MySQL - but more likely related to some firewall settings or Apache settings that prevent flooding, and this is because you're using Ajax (which means that every time you call try to insert it's like a new page refresh). Check both your Apache and your firewall settings - the problem is there.

We have written a post about something similar. [Here it is](http://www.itoctopus.com/your-joomla-website-is-really-really-slow-maybe-you-hit-the-maximum-number-of-apache-clients).

Comment: Thanks so much !! I will look into it and will let you know if it's because of some firewall or Apache setting.